# Powershell .addDays()

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to check if files are older than a year. I get an error Not Icomparable. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this and am stumped.
$file

````
$myDate = Get-Date
$path = $args[0]
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse
foreach($file in $files){
     if($file -gt $myDate.addDays(-365)){
          Write-Host "Found One"
     }
}```
````

Comment: What is `$args[0]`, exactly?

Comment: It's the path to the directory

Comment: @User1990 - you are comparing `$File` to a datetime objects ... but that 1st item is NOT a datetime object - it's a FileInfo object. [*grin*] change that `$File` reference to `$File.LastWriteTime` to compare to a datetime object. ///// also, there is an `.AddYears()` method on datetime objects, so you can use that instead of adding `-365` days. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the files before looping over them. You also need to tell PowerShell you're looking to compare the date of the file, and which date - created, modified etc. At the moment you're saying "if this FileInfo object is less that date", which is why you're getting that error (as per mklement0's comment, FileInfo does not implement IComparable)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $args[0]
foreach ($file in $files) {
     if( $file.LastWriteTime -lt $myDate.addDays(-365)) {
          Write-Host "Found One: $($file.Name)"
     }
}
```

Using `args[0]` is bad practice. Use a named parameter instead

```
Param (
    $Path
)
$myDate = Get-Date
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
...
```

Documentation.

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) - change the parameters if you want to e.g include subdirectories.

[FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties) - this is what you can access in `$files`

Answer (score 1):

One line, if you want to shortly get files which past current year:

```
gci 'd:\temp' | ? { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-365) }
```

Comment: Nice, I got new alias